# grub2 not able to find the new kernel

Tags: linux, kernel, grub2

This is very strange issue, i have CentOS7 running on HP server and everything was working till date until i did "yum install kernel" after reboot it drop me in `grub>` shell that means it won't able to read or find grub.conf file.

in `grub>` i found `grub.conf` has still old files there is no new entries of new kernel

I did this, and found there is no new kernel entries but if i boot with old kernel then i can see latest `grub.conf` (with new kernel)

```
grub>cat /grub2/grub.conf
```

Question: where grub2 getting that old file from? why it's not able to find new kernel ?